# Curl api.telegram блокировка провайдером

Tags: curl, telegram-bot, 1с

Пытаюсь освоить бота в telegram:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot8587****:AAEV4dgrM5Agc6D4cDIut3rzV6IANYY1jw0/sendMessage?chat_id=5066*****&text=hello
```

В адресной строке браузера или в расширение хрома Boomerang успешно отправляет сообщение и получает json. А через curl:

```
curl -X POST https://api.telegram.org/bot8587*****:AAEV4dgrM5Agc6D4cDIut3rzV6IANYY1jw0/sendMessage -d chat_id=5066***** -d text="hello"
```

выходит такое:

> curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed:
>   SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a
>   fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed)

Еще в 1С `HTTPСоединение.Получить(HTTPЗапрос)` выводит

> Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.

Но если я подключаюсь к одному из рабочих vpn, все проходит успешно и в сurl и в 1С. 
Видимо провайдер не дает нормально достучаться до api.telegram? Но как тогда в браузере все проходит отлично без впн?(
Может в curl нужны еще какие-то параметры?

Answer (score 1):

> Пришлось немного напрячь мозг и найти параметр в curl --proxy и через socks5 получилось

вдруг кто-то будет искать:

```
curl -x socks5h://LOGIN:PASS@IP:1080 -L 'https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

соединение описывается для случая HTTPS:// в следующем виде
HTTPСоединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("testdev.elsicon.ru",443,Логин,Пароль, ,TimeOut, Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL(), Ложь);
в случае HTTP:// порт можно не указывать или использовать =80
HTTPСоединение = Новый HTTPСоединение("testdev.elsicon.ru",80,Логин,Пароль, Proxy, TimeOut);

При отправке запроса указывают ресурс равный суффиксу Адреса. В данном примере ИмяРесурса="/payments/1.0/payments.asmx"
Ответ = HTTPСоединение.ОтправитьДляОбработки(ФайлДанныхXML, ИмяРесурса, ФайлОтвета);

Comment: Да я же написал, что в 1С и через curl все проходит успешно, если я подключаю впн, например, Англии
Проблемы именно, когда я обращаюсь напрямую. Но через браузер проблемы нет

Comment: Без VPN и у меня не работает. Думаю, что пока только через него и можно. Если у кого-то есть решение, было бы интересно послушать

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось немного напрячь мозг и найти параметр в curl --proxy и через socks5 получилось